# I clicked on a SMS spam link. Am I safe?

Tags: http, spam, sms

I received an SMS from an unknown number with a link. Having just ordered stuff from AliExpress bit earlier so, thinking it was related to that, I clicked without doing due diligence. My bad.

I went home and tried using a command line tool to get an idea of how bad the situation is.
Similar to [Spam link returns empty redirect to google.com - am I missing something?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193677/spam-link-returns-empty-redirect-to-google-com-am-i-missing-something) I get 301 responses that take me to a known safe website ([www.poste.it](http://www.poste.it), the number is italian and the spam message was about shipping issues, so it's an obvious landing page).

I tried setting the user agent to the same of my phone (from where I clicked), but it still does the same redirects. Laptop and phone are on the same network, so it would be the same IP. Can I infer that I am, somehow, not an interesting target for them? Am I safe?

EDIT: I am not looking for a list of the possible bad effects of clicking on a link, I just want to understand why I am getting a straight 301 redirect from a spam link and if that means there is nothing bad i have to expect after clicking on it from an Android device.

Comment: Do either of these answer your question? [What malicious things can happen when clicking on links in email?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3674/42391) or [Accidently opened a phishing email, is my computer infected by malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/186535/42391)

Comment: both about emails, mine was an SMS :(

Comment: Links are links. It doesn't matter how they were delivered.

Comment: Edited to clarify that the other question doesn't answer me. Yes, links are obviously links, but i'm not looking for a list of malicious things, i'm looking to understand why no malicious things seems to be happening at all.

Comment: Without the link, or access to the webserver's configuration, how are we supposed to know why it responds in a certain way?

Comment: What *could* be happening is that it takes you to an attacker's site that runs several scripts to try to compromise your browser, then dumps you at some benign site once it's done. But that's just one guess (of the many that are possible, hence the duplicate). If you opened it in a malware sandbox, you might get more info.  https://cuckoo.cert.ee/ But, we can't tell you if you are "safe".